# Classify K-means in Text Mining

Tags: data-mining, k-means

The goal is to create a computer-generated news site that aggregates headlines from different news sources around the world:

Taking a look at the centroid table results I want to Understand the following:

https://ibb.co/n1mvnbk

I used K=5
and I am using TF-IDF

Explain what those numbers mean?
When an attribute is zero in multiple clusters, what does it mean?
When I sort the centroid table by each cluster at a descending order, I find some words or attributes that have a higher value with this cluster while zero values in other clusters. Does this mean that these words occur more or less frequently in this cluster? 
How can I discuss the clustering model 
Do all the clusters make sense and why?

Do you think k=5 is a good choice for this dataset? or I need to choose 3? How can I classify that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe K=5 denotes number of cluster you are looking into current Dataset. On the basis 5 centroid will be placed in data will be around them.

**Do you think k=5 is a good choice for this dataset?** Its hard to predict this way. It is all done by mathematical combination and permutation.

You might use **Elbow Method** to identify correct number of cluster needed for any given dataset. This methodology is based on ***WCSS(Within Cluster Sums of Squares)*** which find distance between points and provide centroid points.

Answer (score 0):

Those numbers are the average tf-idf of the cluster. So a 0 means that the word is not in the cluster, and the highest valued words are most characteristic words for the cluster.

Note that for text you'll want to use *spherical* k-means rather than regular k-means.

Choosing k is a big problem. Forget the elbow method, it never works except for you examples. Experiment with different k and choose the one that is most convincing or most useful. None of the usual heuristics for choosing the k in k-means will work here I fear (VRC is IMHO the best). The main reason is that the data *cannot* be well partitioned into k clusters. There is no reason to assume there are exactly k topics in the world, nor that every document only contains one topic. Instead, topics will be a complex structure itself. For example there is Trump, but there also is the Trump Erdogan meeting, and there is the impeachment. These are not disjoint. But you will also have articles that don't fit into any of these topics. This leads to the effect that the true best k would likely be very very large, as large as the number of articles (and hence not useful).